# How do I pass multiple types in a list to a function?

Tags: java, kotlin, types

I want to be able to pass in undefined number of `MyDataStruct` each that takes a type as `dataList`, process that data as its type and return a List of lists keeping the types in order.

I come from a JavaScript/TypeScript background and am trying to learn Kotlin, so this is why I have run into this problem.

```
fun myFunction(
    dataList: List<MyDataStruct<String>, MyDataStruct<Int>, MyDataStruct<Boolean>>
): List<List<String>, List<Int>, List<Boolean>> {
    val data = dataList.map {
        ...mutableListOf<mutableListOf.typeAssiged>
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using classes (instead of tuples). But you can also use tuples in Kotlin, you have to search for "decomposition".

Comment: Can you show a JavaScript equivalent of what you're doing so we can better understand?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce These are all classes, I am not using `Tuples`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `vararg` declaration for that:

```
fun myFunction(vararg dataList: MyDataStruct) {
    // code can use dataList as an array / list of MyDataStruct

}
```

This could fall apart with the type parameters you specify on `MyDataStruct` however, but you could still handle differing values in the object with a `when` clause.

For example (assuming you're keeping a value property in your data struct):

```
for(myDataStruct in dataList) {
    when (myDataStruct.value) {
        is Int -> {/*do something with int*/}
        is String -> {/*do something with string*/}
        is Boolean -> {/*do something with boolean*/}
        else -> {/*do something else*/}
    }

}
```

Lastly, the brackets (`{}`) after the arrows in each `when` statement are optional IF you have a one line function call.  The current example is a bunch of empty anonymous functions that should compile but won't do anything. You'd also need those brackets if you needed to do a multi-line function for when the value is of a specific type.